# cudaMemcpy replace existing values?

Tags: cuda

I am making a program in cuda 4.2 and I am having this problem...

I need to execute the same code to 2 images. So I put the code in a `for` loop and I am calling all the `cudaMalloc` once before the for loop. The code in the the loop uses `cudaMemcpy(..,..,..,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)` to the same device array pointer. So I thought that the new values (from the first image) would replace the old ones (from the second image) in the second loop. But `cudaMemcpy(..,..,..,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)` fails...

Do i have to use another function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know what error it gives? try using [cudaGetErrorString](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__ERROR_g38e5684c158c22144ad3c269ad61bc78.html)

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

I had a potentially similar problem,
It turned out I was calling cudaFree() inside at the end of the loop but cudaMalloc() only once before the loop. 
This meant when I tried to copy over the values onto the GPU after the first time the memory was no longer allocated, I ended up making sure CudaMalloc and CudaFree were all outside the loop and it worked fine.